# How to Login with Azure AD Single Sign-on account using JIRA API to perform JIRA actions

Tags: authentication, jira, jira-rest-api, rest, jira-rest-java-api

I'm trying to use JIRA API for creating story, task or bug on JIRA tool but account needs to be login first for performing all operations. I have my Azure AD account used for JIRA login on UI but I'm unable to find a way to login using JIRA API. Community, please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jira's REST API can't use Azure credentials for authentication. Depending on whether you're connecting to Jira Cloud or Jira Server, it uses OAuth, keys and tokens, or usernames and passwords.

Refer to this [Security overview page](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/security-overview/) for all the methods supported.

Comment: Thanks David ! It worked when I tried using JIRA API token for my account

Comment: No problem. Also, the etiquette on Stack Overflow is, if the answer is correct, then mark it as correct. This lets other who search the topic know which answers are accepted as correct.